# JavaScript - Check What Page Has Loaded?

Tags: javascript, load

Is there a way to ask JavaScript what web page is currently loaded?

Example:

```
if(page loaded == index.php){
   do something
}
else if(page loaded == contact.php){
   do something else
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
if(sPage == "index.php"){
   do something
}
else if(sPage  == "contact.php"){
   do something else
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could look at [`window.location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), that will give you this:

```
"/questions/8102940/javascript-check-what-page-has-loaded"
```

for this question page.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `document.URL` to find out what page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You could use document.URL.includes. Then it will be something like this:

```
if(document.URL.includes("index.php")){
   do something
}
else if(document.URL.includes("contact.php")){
   do something else
}
```

I know this is a bit late, but i hope this helps for other people.